# PancakeSwap Execution Reverted

Tags: web3js, blockchain, python, pancakeswap

I've been tring to code a bot to run on pancakeSwap and for some reason, all the transactions I try with this script keep getting reverted.

```
API_URL = 'https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/' #testnet
CONTRACT_ID = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0xc3f9c723ce06ee0fa420c8c88cee115fa0147748')

SENDER_ADDRESS = '00'
SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY = '00'

ROUTER_ADDRESS = '0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1' #pancakeswap V2 router tesnet
Spend = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0xed24fc36d5ee211ea25a80239fb8c4cfd80f12ee') #spend binance 

Receive = CONTRACT_ID
max_approval_hex = f"0x{64 * 'f'}"
max_approval_int = int(max_approval_hex, 16)
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(API_URL))
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=ROUTER_ADDRESS, abi=ABI)

erc_20_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=Spend, abi=ERC20_ABI)
nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(SENDER_ADDRESS)

#send coin to router
approve_txn = erc_20_contract.functions.transferFrom(SENDER_ADDRESS, ROUTER_ADDRESS, 1).buildTransaction({
    'from': SENDER_ADDRESS,
    'gas': w3.toWei('250000', 'wei'),
    'nonce':  nonce,
})
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(approve_txn, private_key=SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY)
w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)  

#approve the coin
approve_txn = erc_20_contract.functions.approve(ROUTER_ADDRESS, max_approval_int).buildTransaction({
    'from': SENDER_ADDRESS,
    'gas': w3.toWei('250000', 'wei'),
    'nonce': nonce + 1,
})
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(approve_txn, private_key=SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY)
w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)  

start = time.time()
pancakeswap_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    100,
    10,
    [Spend, Receive],
    SENDER_ADDRESS,
    (int(time.time()) + 1000000)
).buildTransaction({
    'from': SENDER_ADDRESS,
    'gas': 100000,
    'gasPrice': w3.toWei('100', 'gwei'),
    'nonce':  nonce + 2,
})
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(approve_txn, 
              private_key=SENDER_PRIVATE_KEY)
w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

I've tried approving and not approving and the results are the same.
I'm running on binance TestNet and I have BNB on my testnet wallet.

Comment: Why are you calling transferFrom from sender to router for 1 wei? Also `'gas': w3.toWei('250000', 'wei'),` is the same as `'gas': 250000,`

Comment: I dont really understand that part. Anyway, I think that pancakeswap router already handles the approval do I dont think thats needed. What i think is the problem is the contract IDs Im using, how do I find the right IDs for each token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i figured it out. It turns out I was using too less gas.